# Crazy CSS Positioning

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a very strange CSS problem. I have 3 divs all with the same code and same amount of text. Within the div there is a button that links to a page. On one of the buttons there is an invisible gap between the paragraph and the button. It is not padding or margin and there is not any code in between. I have inspected the element in firefox and ie and have the same issue in both browsers. It can be seen here http://northlondon.builders It is the centre box on the homepage. I have never seen such a gap before with no apparent reason for it. I am not being lazy here, I honestly can not see why this is happening. Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Comment: Quick! A typo! Everyone answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got an

```
&nbsp;
```

between your .service-desc p and your .pbtn p

Comment: When looking at the code in Firebug (or some other inspector tool), did that show up as &nbsp; or just whitespace (no actual escape character)?

Comment: On any inspector it should display &nbsp; as the inspector displays the HTML code for the DOM and not the rendered results.

Comment: For some reason, my firebug doesn't show a &nbsp; character? I'm going to post what I did to fix it even though your answer sounds like it would fix the root cause (even though I can't see it)

Answer (score 1):

There is a line-break and a non breakable space (`&nbsp;`) after the paragraph!!

You should inspect the source code to find such things.

Pay attention to line breaks in your html code. A space is a character and will be rendered as text.

Comment: I could not see that. It seems like joomla was adding it because of a space between lines in the editor. It is not normally fussy about how you lay out the code in the editor. When I looked in firebug and ie there was absolutely no difference in the code. I took a screenshot to show this http://northlondon.builders/aaa.png  and it was caused by the line break in this one http://northlondon.builders/aaaa.jpg . Any way thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like karlipoppins has the right answer but I could not see the `&nbsp;` character. So in case that didn't work you could do this:

```
<p class="pbtn" style="margin-top:-17px">
```

It is kinda ugly but it fixed it for me.

...
Edited:

Ok now I see the `&nbsp;` in Chrome developer tools. Firebug didn't show it. I'm kinda sad now because I love firebug and use it all the time. This seems like a reason not to use it anymore.

Comment: OK Thank you I thought I was going mad and was about to get attacked!

Comment: Removing the line space between the 2 p elements in the editor fixed the problem. There is a screenshot above showing where it was.